# Where was the Wakandan Air Force?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Why didn't Wakanda use their jets/ships, specifically to destroy Thanos' army as they came through the gap in the shield, and generally in the battle?

Comment: According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/8ofd5i/mcu_what_happened_to_all_those_wakandan_planes/) and the [MCU wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Wakanda) they took part in destroying the dropships.

Comment: Also in a blink-and-you'll-miss scene, the Wakandan ships can be seen attacking the big vertical ships in the background.

Comment: It will be useless to have the planes attack drop bombs on the battlefield since both sides were on it.

Comment: they dont need to drop bombs they have some sort of focused laser weapon

Answer (score 23):

They appear in a few scenes during the battle of Wakanda, presumably having been held in reserve while the close fighting is taking place. They do make an appearance when the subterranean wheel things erupt from the ground.

[image]

You see them picking off larger targets a few minutes later

[image]

And attacking the drop ships a few minutes after that

[image]

Comment: +1 Another scene showing the aircraft happens later when Thor is attacking the retreating landing craft.